# Convert alphanumeric string to 16 digit GCID

Tags: openoffice-calc

I'm building our inventory feed for Amazon Seller Central in OpenOffice Calc but can't work out how to convert our inhouse product IDs to the Amazon required format GCID.

> The standard-product-id must have a specific number of characters according to type: GCID (16 alphanumeric characters), UPC (12 digit number), EAN (13 digit number) or GTIN(14 digit number).

Our product IDs vary by manufacturer, eg:-

> 123456
>   AB123456
>   1234AB

Where the ID is numerical only I can format the cells with leading zeros, however this doesn't work if the cell contains letters.

My file has over 10,000 products so I'm wondering if there is a formula I can apply to all cells to instantly convert them to GCID?

Comment: Is the conversion from UPC/EAN/GTIN to GCID just adding leading zeroes, or some actual meaning must be extracted and re-encoded? For example, do 1234AB becomes 00000000001234AB?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the question was asked when under a misapprehension but having noticed that the example `123456 AB123456 1234AB` represents three different IDs and aware that padding to a specified length is quite a common requirement (eg see [String.PadLeft Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07(v=vs.110).aspx)) a suggestion for OpenOffice might be of use to someone, one day.

Convention is to pad with `0`s but since some spreadsheets automatically strip these off the front of numbers (as first example) and databases tend to prefer that fields are of consistent format I suggest separating the padding from the example with a hyphen, to aid identification of alpha numeric codes and to force text format:

```
 =REPT(0;15-LEN(A1))&"-"&A1
```